# How do I get Knights of the Old Republic (KOTOR) to run on Windows 8?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, windows-8, star-wars-kotor

I have a nVidia GTX 560 Ti with the latest drivers as of this post (311.06).
I run `swkotor.exe` with compatibility mode set to XP SP3, and as administrator. The game starts up, but about 8 minutes into the first level, when fighting the first of the Sith, it crashes.
Already tried the following from `swconfig.exe`:

- Disable v-sync
- Disable hardware mouse cursor
- Disable movies

Also, I have the original 4 CD retail pack, not Steam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was some problem with `swkotor.exe`. I downloaded a noCD crack and now it works fine. (The irony!)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you have the retail version but this [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/32370/discussions/0/828927580792423902/) user had the same problem try going into settings and disabling grass. Worked for at least one person could work for you.  Hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Nope, didn't work. The game works upto the cutscene showing Sith fighting Republican troops, after that when you engage them in combat, it crashes.